# Extbase complex query problems

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I got a complex data structure like this:

```
leve1Model->1:level2Model->n:level3Model->1:value1
                                        ->1:level4Model->1:value2
```

What I need is to find all level1Model instances which's level2Model instance contains one level3Model instance which has a certain value1 and which's level4Model instance also has a certain value2.

I am relatively new to Extbase and it's Database abstraction, but I figured I could do something like:

```
$query->contains('level2Model.level3Model.value1', val1),
```

but this gives me an error about an unsupported property `value1`. But even if it worked I don't know how I would make sure that the contained instance also meets the required `level4Model->1:value2`condition.

So is there a way to properly use the abstraction layer for this kind of query (and how would I go about that?) or do I have to resort to plain sql?

Answer (score 0):

The query builder will not help you much here. If the second level model is stored within an object storage you could query against the uids of these objects. But that's as far as the query builder will take you. Your query is too complex. You would have to split the query into multiple parts and re-filter the results but the performance might be bad. I would suggest using the helper functions for sanitation etc. but passing it the finished sql statement parts (fields, from, where etc. ). Alternatively you could rethink the data structure of this is an essential part of your app to make it more extbase compliant.